# interpolation of missing values in time series

Tags: python, time-series, interpolation

I have a dateset that looks like this (showing the tail end of data)-

```
  YearMonth Rose

172 1994-05  44.0

173 1994-06  45.0

174 1994-07  NaN

175 1994-08  NaN

176 1994-09  46.0

177 1994-10  51.0

178 1994-11  63.0
```

As you can see, there are two missing values. To correct it i am using the following code-

```
 df.interpolate(method='spline',order=1, limit=2)['Rose']
```

But its not working. It still shows that there are null values. What am i doing wrong? How to fix it?

Also, no index has been set and datatypes are object and float for 'Year Month' and Rose respectively.

Comment: please provide the dataset as text, or better DataFrame constructor

Comment: You probably need to assign it back to the original dataframe...

Comment: 'df' is the original dataframe